# Solving dependency conflicts between com.android.support:support-compat and androidx.core:core

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-support-library, androidx

I'm still novice with Android and I want to create an app that has a navigation drawer and gets location updates. After creating a project with navigation drawer, I have dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Then I go through this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates
and it needs these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But when I put them together they conflict and I cannot find a way to solve them.

I tried adding exclusions, migrating to androidx, but all this doesn't help. I either get conflict like this:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
```

Or some conflicting packages if I try to fix manifest:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
```

Is there a way to solve this so that both UI and Location works?

Comment: have you added android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true to your build.gradle?

Comment: AFAIK androidx package can't be worked together with support libs

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu just tried it. Doesn't seem to help. This solves the merge manifest error but then it doesn't see imports such as android.support.annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

This version uses the support libraries and you can't use androidx and support libraries together.

Use an [**updated version**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) of `play-services-location` migrated to androidx.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```